# In F# type providers how do I add a static class to a provided type?

Tags: f#, type-providers

How can I add a type to another `ProvidedType`, specifying that that type is a static class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not immediately obvious how to do this but all you have to do is add the appropriate metadata attributes in the form of `TypeAttributes`:

```
//create a providedtype
let myStaticType = ProvidedTypeDefinition("Tags", Some typeof<obj>, isErased = false)

//set the TypeAttributes on the type
myStaticType.SetAttributes (TypeAttributes.Public ||| TypeAttributes.Class ||| TypeAttributes.Sealed ||| TypeAttributes.Abstract)

//Add the static type to another type
parentType.AddMember myStaticType
```

A static type is simply a type that has the Abstract and Sealed `TypeAttributes`